# Paypal 10400 error Order total is missing

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

i've already checked all answers about this question, but i can't find something which makes it works.

I'm trying to customize a paypal payement, but either nothing appears in the description either i got the order total is missing answer.

I've read that i must do DoExpressCheckout before SetExpressCheckout, with same parameters except return and cancel, but i got the 'Specified method is not supported', so i don't know what to do.

I took the code from here:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECCustomizing/

```
&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout
&RETURNURL=http://...
&CANCELURL=http://...
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=10% Decaf Kona Blend Coffee
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=623083
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=Size: 8.8-oz
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=9.95
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=2
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1=Coffee Filter bags
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER1=623084
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC1=Size: Two 24-piece boxes
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1=39.70
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1=2
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=99.30
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=2.58
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=3.00
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT=2.99
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT=-3.00
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT=1.00
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=105.87
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD
&ALLOWNOTE=1
```

I've already tried my informations (user, pwd, signature, logo...) with just this:
    &METHOD=SetExpressCheckout
    &AMT=10.00
and it works.

Now i want to put a description of the item, but  i always get 'Order total is missing'.

API Response:

```
TIMESTAMP=2015%2d09%2d09T09%3a03%3a23Z
&CORRELATIONID=2f370dfafc18
&ACK=Failure
&VERSION=98%2e0
&BUILD=17972692
&L_ERRORCODE0=10400
 &L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Transaction%20refused%20because%20of%20an%20invalid%20argument%2e%20See%20additional%20error%20messages%20for%20details%2e
&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Order%20total%20is%20missing%2e
&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error
```

Did i missed something ?

Comment: I test your script, no issue. could you share the API response? thanks !

Comment: Question edited with API response

Comment: In PayPal's log, you didn't pass PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT to PayPal, please examine your code and make sure you passed all parameters to PayPal correctly. Thanks !

Comment: What you see is my link... i separated parameters to be clear on my questions, but there is my link and 
    &PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=10.00 is on my link, so please tell me what i need to do to pass this parameter to PayPal

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your API call logs and noticed that PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT was not correctly passed to PayPal during your test. The API request code is working as expected now. Please test and confirm again.

Comment: Same error. What can i do to send it correctly? Maybe should i change the version or the server...?